# stack overflow method

Tags: operating-system

In some operating system,for any process there is a stack and a heap.Both grows towards each other.There must be a guard band between them to check for overlapping.Can anyone give me some illustration about it.I want to write my own function for checking stack overflow error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a system like that, you would normally have a guard word or something similar at the top of the heap, something like `0xa55a` or `0xdeadbeef`.

Then, periodically, that guard word is checked to see if it's been corrupted. If so something has overwritten the memory.

Now this may not *necessarily* be a stack overflow, it may be a rogue memory write. But, in both those cases, something is seriously wrong so you may as well treat them the same.

Of course, more modern operating systems may take the approach of using the assistance of the hardware such as in the Intel chips. In those, you can set up a stack segment to a specific size and, if you try to write outside of there (using the stack selector), you'll get a trap raised.

The heap in that case would be using a different selector so as to be kept separate.

Comment: usually the compiler does. it might be a static value, something random generated at compile time or even something calculated for each call. totally implementation-specific.

Comment: The OS (or C library or whatever) knows what it is because the OS (or C library or whatever) put it there.

Comment: @pax when you are limiting your stack size with the help of h/w then your program can not be cross platform and will be h/w dependent.

Comment: @daniel if it static value and if you use the same value in your program for some variable then it will behave in unwanted way.so it must be decided at runtime.

Comment: that's not really a problem as you are not supposed to work with the canary anyway. of course you shouldn't use something like 0, but rather some pseudo-random value. the main advantage of deciding the value at runtime is that static analysis of the software will not expose the canary value to exploit writers. accidently using the current canary value for some variable wouldn't be a smart idea, but wouldn't cause problems right away either.

Answer (score 1):

Many operating systems place a guard page (or similar techniques) between stack and heap to protect against such attack vectors. I haven't seen canaries (the method mentioned by paxdiablo) there yet, they're mostly used to guard against stack-internal overflows (aka to guard the return address).

Guard pages on Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366549(VS.85).aspx

Linux had an interesting exploit based on this problem some time ago though: http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Root-privileges-through-Linux-kernel-bug-Update-1061563.html